# How do you cover an area in tiles(images) in python / pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, tile

What i want to do is have (0,390),(0,450),(610,390),(610,450) - covered in a tile image called (brick_tile). so far all i have is this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

cloud_background = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp')
brick_tile = pygame.image.load('brick_tile.png')

pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(cloud_background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(brick_tile,(0,450))
    pygame.display.flip()

    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tile with bricks you just have to blit, blit, blit in a loop:

```
import pygame
import sys
import itertools

cloud_background = pygame.image.load('clouds.bmp')
brick_tile = pygame.image.load('brick_tile.png')

pink = (255, 64, 64)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
running = 1

def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(cloud_background,(0,0))
    brick_width, brick_height = brick_tile.get_width(), brick_tile.get_height()
    for x,y in itertools.product(range(0,610+1,brick_width),
                                 range(390,450+1,brick_height)):
        # print(x,y)
        screen.blit(brick_tile, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()

while running:
    setup_background()    
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
```

Comment: OK I  added that to the end of the program. and the bricks do not apear

Comment: You need to call the function: `setup_background()`. I've edited the code to show what I mean.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Enrique\Dropbox\GAMEZ_PYGAME\gamez.py", line 14, in <module>
    setup_background()
NameError: name 'setup_background' is not defined`

Comment: Since you are getting that error on line 14, chances are you are calling `setup_background()` before defining the function with `def setup_background():`.  I've also added a runnable example above.